# Using Plink and redirect output in bash script

Tags: bash, redirect, output, plink

I've got problem, I've setup plink to create a connection to a BlueCoat device, retrieve the full configuration and redirect the output to a file.

The problem is, when I try it from the script, the output of plink is displayed on screen and not redirected to the file, but if I use the same exact command interactively, it works!

I've checked the file rights, etc. they all seem to be ok.

The way I use it is:

```
/usr/bin/plink -4 -batch -ssh -l <user> -pw <password> -m /tmp/bluecoat.backup <hostname> > output.txt
```

Any clues?

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: maybe it has something to do with my script...before I run that command, I use a command to log everything...and the output of the plink appears in that logfile. I use `exec 1>logs/$(date +%Y%m%d)_activity.log 2>&1`

Comment: You have answered your own question, you should post the answer  along with your fix.

Comment: But I would still like to log everything from the script...AND output the plink to a separate file. Not sure on how to do that though...

Comment: Stop redirection before the plink line, and restart redirection and it completes. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80988/how-to-stop-redirection-in-bash